# Setting environment variables permanently under GNU-Linux systems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, environment-variables

I was using the command export, but it looks that after some time the set variables disappears. What is the easiest way of setting an environment variable forever?

Thanks

Comment: See also: [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The export variables in the .profile or .bash_profile are available when you start a terminal only and not visible to applications started outside the terminal. Use the /etc/environment to make the variables available to all the applications outside the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

According to the version of Linux, and assuming the standard bash shell is used, the user in question will have a .profile or .bash_profile file in their home folder (it's the latter in Ubuntu). You can use your favourite editor to add the variable definition there - for example:

**Before:**

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

**After:**

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
MYVARIABLE=THISVALUE

export PATH MYVARIABLE
```

The *export* command pushes the variable out into the child environment so it's available to other scripts and processes. You don't have to pile up the variable names behind a single export command, you can also do the whole definition and export in one go eg:

```
export MYVARIABLE=THISVALUE
```

Global variables for everyone can be set in a similar way in */etc/profile*

Comment: Note that the last one only works in bash. Older shells don't allow it.